# How can I safely stop my "class implements Runnable"?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, runnable

The [Oracle Java SE Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) recommend doing this:

*You can avoid the use of Thread.stop by replacing the applet's stop and run methods with:*

```
private volatile Thread blinker;

public void stop() {
    blinker = null;
}

public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing for a `class blinker implements Runnable` ?

As you would have to use `blinker thisClass = this;` or similar, wouldn't the `(blinker == thisClass)` always evaluate as true?

Or will this code suffice:

```
class blinker implements Runnable {
    boolean stop = false;

    @override
    public void run() {

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            // code
            // ...

            if (stop) { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }

            // ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I.. don't believe Oracle recommends that.  The usual way is `Thread.interrupt()`.  No there's no equivalent for `Runnable`, just use `Thread.interrupt()` or `Future.cancel(true)` as appropriate.

Comment: @markspace [I wouldn't have believed it either](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: I just read that.   It seems a terrible idea.  Just because it's Oracle doesn't mean they can't publish poorly thought out code.  I think the main idea here is "don't call Thread.stop()".  Anything else is a kludge.  OP: use *Thread.interrupt()*.

Comment: so a `while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { }` with a `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` inside is completely safe?

Comment: @markspace At that point in the doc, they weren't covering blocked threads. The next section on that page covers interrupting. That part is explaining the alternative to stopping, which although not explained in the best way, is pretty important to know. I do agree that the documentation was horribly written.

Comment: @Willdorf Check out my answer. I have edited it to  (hopefully) cover what you are asking about

Comment: Note that the documentation is **not** saying to override `Thread.stop`. These are `run` and `stop` methods of some class that **already implements Runnable**, as demonstrated by the `blinker = new Thread(this)` earlier in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like that:

```
class Blinker implements Runnable {
    Runnable blinker = this;

    public void stop() {
        blinker = null;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(blinker == this) {

        }
    }
}
```

But it would be pretty pointless. *I don't think you're understanding the point the documentation is trying to get across*, which is **don't use an infinite loop to keep threads alive, using `Thread#stop()` to terminate them**. Instead, use a condition, then set it to false when you want to end the loop which is keeping the thread alive.

---

You do not need to constantly check `Thread#isInterrupted()` to keep the thread alive.

```
while(!stop) {

}
```

Would do just fine. You also should not interrupt the thread from within the thread. The purpose of interrupting is to end tasks that halt the thread. These tasks are surround within `try/catch` which catches an `InterruptedException`. Other threads are usually the ones in charge of interrupting.

---

The documentation is referring to allowing the thread to die gracefully.

In the first example, the `run()` method was handled via an infinite loop: `while(true)`. The only way to stop the thread would be to forcing some kind of stop, such as usong `Thread#stop`:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

But it's not recommended to use `Thread#stop`. Instead, the loop should depend on a `boolean`, which another thread (or the current one) could set to `true` or `false`:

```
private volatile boolean running;

public void stop() {
    running = false;
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Instead of using a `running` boolean, they used `blinker == thisThread`, then changed the value of `blinker` when they wanted to end the loop:

```
private volatile Thread blinker;

public void stop() {
    blinker = null;
}

public void run() {
    Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    while (blinker == thisThread) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interval);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer OP's question of "what if `blinker` is an instance of a class which implements `Runnable`?" (paraphrasing).

Comment: Why are you swallowing `InterruptedException`'s?

Comment: @dimo414 It's code straight from the documentation. I simply made a few modifications to show the purpose of the code. The exceptions were swallowed to begin it, I wanted to stay consistent with the documentation.